# How to find and copy previous latest file created larger than a custom size?

Tags: batch-file

I wrote a batch file which should find and copy the latest build file bigger than a 3.5 GB.

```
set source=D:\src
set tmp_dir="D:\tmp"

set "file="
for /f "delims=|" %%a in ('
    dir /b /o-d "%source%\*.zip" 2^>nul
    ^| cmd /q /v /c"set /p .=&if defined . (echo(!.!)"
') do set "file=%%a" 
echo %file%

robocopy %source% %tmp_dir% %file% /MT:16 /X /MIN:3500000000 /XO /V /TS /FFT /R:3 /W:10 /ETA
```

My problem is what happening when the latest file is smaller than 3.5 GB. In this case is need to copy the next file larger than 3.5 GB.

Comment: So what you ask for is a way to check the file size of the given file, check if it exceeds 3.5 GB and if not, continue with the next file. Correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right.Something like: 10 files was created today

Comment: Something like: 10 files was created today: 8 files > 3.5 GB, but the latest files has 1 KB (damaged builds). Check the next from list: not good (also smaller than 3.5 GB). And so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the size of a file in bit using the following line

```
for /f "usebackq" %%a in ('%file%') d set filesize=%%~za
```

Add

```
set /a filesize+=0
```

to make sure it is treated like a numeric variable.

Then use an `if`-statement to check if filesize exceeds 3500000000 byte -> 3.5 GB.

```
if filesize LSS 3500000000 (
  echo not 3.5 GB
) ELSE (
  echo bigger than 3.5 GB
)
```

Adding other `echo`es is up to you.

Comment: I'm not sure how to modify my script according with your suggestion because it was a error displayed: "in('') was unexpected at this time."

Comment: There seems to be a simple typo in the first line of code: there is a *space* missing in between `in` and `(`... the number `28 000 000 000` does not make any sense though as the size is already returned in terms of bytes, but not bits; hence `3 500 000 000` was actually correct...

Answer (score 3):

You almost have it. Instead of using the `dir` command to retrieve the initial list of files, we can use `robocopy` to get a list (`/l`) of files in the source folder with the required minimum size (`/min`). This list should not include job header, job footer, nor directory list (`/njh`, `/njf`, `/ndl`). For each file we don't need the class of the file (`/nc`) or the size of the file (`/ns`), but we want the time stamp (`/ts`) of the files to sort the list on this field.

This will leave a sorted list of files with the newer file matching the conditions as the first in the list.

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "source=D:\src"
    set "tmp_dir=D:\tmp"

    set "file="
    for /f "tokens=2,*" %%a in ('
        robocopy "%source%" . *.zip /l /xx /is /njh /njs /ndl /nc /ns /ts /min:350000000000
        ^| sort /r
        ^| cmd /q /v /c"set /p .=&if defined . (echo(!.!)"
    ') do set "file=%%~nxb" 
    echo(%file%

    if defined file (
        robocopy "%source%" "%tmp_dir%" "%file%" /MT:16 /X /XO /V /TS /FFT /R:3 /W:10 /ETA    
    )
```

Comment: Was need to modify your script due a little typo, but worked perfect after that

Comment: Also I modified the output of the %file% due displayed also the path. Something like that:   set file=%file:~7,6%  (works with my test files e.g. 05.txt)

Comment: @Deco, My fault. I've changed the variable assignment to only get the name and extension of the file, without the path.

Comment: Just I have seen another problem: the folder contains many build files and the script stop working even o local works perfectly. I don't understand why:    the echo displayed the name of the script file instead of name of the build

Comment: @Deco, added the `.zip` extension that I forget to include.

Comment: with latest change echo return: echo(  or (after I deleted "(" from latest echo from script):  >echo
ECHO is on.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong: I forgot to modify the size according with my test files

Comment: I re-tested with my work environment and work perfectly. Great job!

Comment: Nice work, +1! I suggest to add the `/xx` option to avoid `*.zip` files in the current directory (`.`) to be listed (as Extra files) unintentionally. Why are you using `sort /r` and the `cmd` command line to get the latest item? it would also work if you use `sort` without `/r` and let `for /f` get the latest item...

Comment: @aschipfl, copied from OP question (and I think I was who wrote that code). The problem with `for /f` when reading the output of a command is that the required time grows exponentially. The `sort /r` ensures the first line contains the needed line and the `| cmd` is just a `head -n 1` to ensure the `for /f` will only process one line and not a large list of files (probably not the case in this question). Good point the `/xx`

Comment: I did not realise the code was already used in the question; anyway, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @MC ND, I'm not sure why is  "("  in  "echo(%file%" . For me wasn't work and I supposed is a typo

Comment: @Deco, If `%file%` does not have content `echo %file%` is parsed as `echo` and the result is a `ECHO is off` to console. `echo(%file%` will simple output a empty line if the variable is not defined.